# I'm in trouble with the survey portal with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, list, survey, radiobuttonfor

Select a survey In the view, fill in the survey according to the id of the survey selected by the user, and view the survey's questions.The part I can't do is save the options the user chooses and which option belongs to which question in the database.

In these codes, the view page where users select a poll

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ANKET ID</th>
                <th>ANKET BAŞLIĞI</th>
                <th>ANKET BAŞLAMA TARİHİ</th>
                <th>ANKET BİTİŞ TARİHİ</th>
                <th>SEÇ</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SelectSurvey", "Survey", FormMethod.Post))
            { 
            foreach (var liste in Model)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>@liste.ID</td>
                    <td>@liste.SurveyName</td>
                    <td>@liste.SurveyStartDate</td>
                    <td>@liste.SurveyFinishDate</td>
                    <td><a href="~/Survey/FillSurvey/@liste.ID" class="btn btn-primary">SEÇ</a></td>
                </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

controller I created for surveys

```
namespace anketPortali.Controllers
{
    public class SurveyController : Controller
    {

        MySurveyEntities5 db = new MySurveyEntities5();
        // GET: Survey

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult NewSurvey()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult SelectSurvey()
        {
            var model = db.SurveyHeader.ToList();
            return View(model);
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult FillSurvey(int id)
        {
            var model = db.Questions.Where(x => x.SurveyID == id).ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

image of the page to be filled in the survey

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                @foreach (var liste in Model)
                {
                    using (Html.BeginForm("FillSurvey", "Survey", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h3><span class="label label-warning" id="qid">@liste.ID</span>@liste.Question</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-5">
                                <div id="loadbar" style="" display="none">
                                    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_01"></div>
                                    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_02"></div>
                                    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_03"></div>
                                    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_04"></div>
                                    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_05"></div>
                                    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_06"></div>
                                    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_07"></div>
                                    <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_08"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="quiz" id="answers" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="element-animation2 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span><input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="1">@liste.Option1</label>
                            <label class="element-animation2 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span><input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="2">@liste.Option2</label>
                            <label class="element-animation2 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span><input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="3">@liste.Option3</label>
                            <label class="element-animation2 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span><input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="4">@liste.Option4</label>
                            <label class="element-animation2 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span><input type="radio" name="q_answer" value="2">@liste.Option5</label>
                    }
                }
                <br />
                <input type="submit" id="btnBitir" class="btn btn-success" value="Anketi Bitir" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please don't show images of code, but add as text

Comment: I have arranged

Comment: Can you please explain more why you can't do what you are trying to achieve? Are you getting an error? Are you struggling to get the user's selections through to the backend? Some more detail on your challenge would be helpful.

Comment: There is no problem in the display part, but I cannot transfer to the controller part which user chooses which option, so I cannot register to the database.

Comment: is there anyone who can tell me how ?